# Correct answer, wrong method in improper integral problem.

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Note: this is a problem from a class, but my solution has already been submitted and the assignment is locked for all students so this shouldn't break any sort of academic honesty guidelines.

$$\int_{0}^{\ln{3}}\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^\frac{2}{3}}dx$$

I understand that this is an improper integral given $\frac{e^0}{(e^0 - 1)^\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{0}$, but I seem to have come to the right answer without using any improper integration techniques. Through two layers of u-substitution $u = e^x$ and $v = u - 1$, my answer comes to $3 \cdot 2^\frac{1}{3}$. Every online calculator I've checked with confirms that this is correct, but I don't understand *why* it seems to be correct without any use of improper integration techniques. This hints at some disconnect I've got with improper integrals or u-substitution, and I'm really at a loss for what it might be.

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Basically, this is for the same reason you can formally write $\int_0^1 x^{-2/3} \, dx = \left.3x^{1/3}\right.|_0^1 = 3$ even though the integral is improper.  You are implicitly evaluating it as $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon ^1 x^{-2/3} \, dx$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the integral is improper at the lower bound, it is defined as $\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \int_\epsilon^{\ln 3}$. Let us look at what happens:
$$
\int_{\epsilon}^{\ln{3}}\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^\frac{2}{3}}dx
= \{ u=e^x \}
= \int_{e^\epsilon}^{3} \frac{u}{(u-1)^\frac{2}{3}} \frac{du}{u}
= \int_{e^\epsilon}^{3} \frac{du}{(u-1)^\frac{2}{3}} \\
= \{v=u-1\} 
= \int_{e^\epsilon-1}^{2} \frac{dv}{v^\frac{2}{3}}
= \int_{e^\epsilon-1}^{2} v^{-\frac{2}{3}} \, dv
= \left[ \frac{1}{3}v^{\frac{1}{3}} + C \right]_{e^\epsilon-1}^{2} \\
= \frac{1}{3} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{3}} - \frac{1}{3} (e^\epsilon-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}
.
$$
Taking limits we find that
$\frac{1}{3} (e^\epsilon-1)^{\frac{1}{3}} \to 0 = \frac{1}{3} (e^0-1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$
as $\epsilon \to 0,$ i.e. the primitive function **is defined and continuous at $0$**. And that is the reason it works.

Another example is the improper integral $\int_0^1 \ln x \, dx$. For this we get
$$
\int_\epsilon^1 \ln x \, dx = \left[ x\ln x - x \right]_\epsilon^1
= (1\ln 1-1) - (\epsilon\ln\epsilon-\epsilon).
$$
Here the lower bound term is not defined for $\epsilon=0$ and we can not just insert $\epsilon=0$ but really need to take limits (which result in $0$ so the full integral has value $-1$).

Comment: This was extremely helpful, thanks so much! I feel like I've got a much clearer picture of what's really going on now.

Answer (score 0):

We can perform a somewhat different substitution of the form $$u^{-3} = e^x - 1, \quad -3u^{-4} du = e^x \, dx.$$  This maps the endpoints of integration from $x = 0$ to $u = \infty$ and $x = \log 3$ to $u = 2^{-1/3}$, and the integral becomes
$$\int_{u=\infty}^{2^{-1/3}} u^2 (-3u^{-4}) \, du = 3 \int_{u=2^{-1/3}}^\infty u^{-2} \, du.$$  Then we can apply the usual procedures:  $$3 \int_{u=2^{-1/3}}^\infty u^{-2} \, du = 3 \lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{u=2^{-1/3}}^N u^{-2} \, du = 3\lim_{N \to \infty} \left[- \frac{1}{u} \right]_{u=2^{-1/3}}^N = 3(2^{1/3}) - 3\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} = 3(2^{1/3}).$$

Answer (score -1):

Let $u = e^x -1$.  Then $du = e^x\, dx$.  Your integral becomes
$$\int_0^2 {du\over u^{2/3}}.$$
This integral integrates at zero because the power is less than 1.

Comment: That should be $du$, not $dx$. The integral is improper. And your justification is... not really accurate. I mean, for *proper* integrals the justification is not true. And for this one, $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\epsilon}^2 u^{-2/3}\,du = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}3u^{1/3}\bigm|^2_{\epsilon} = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}(3\sqrt[3]{2}-3\sqrt[3]{\epsilon}) = 3\sqrt[3]{2}$.

Comment: So?  The integral integrate on the interval.

Comment: Substitution can tame an improper integral.

Comment: So? You claim the value of the integral is $0$ “because the power is less than $1$”. That’s a false assertion. An integral over $[0,2]$ of a power of $x$ is not equal to zero if the exponent is smaller than $1$. Your integral is not proper on the interval, and if you integrate ignoring that fact, fine, you still don’t get zero. So pretty much all of your assertions after doing the substitution are false.

Comment: $x \mapsto x^{-a}$ integrates at zero if $a < 1$

Comment: Confusion; I thought you were saying the value of the integral *is* $0$; sorry for that. You are still playing fast and loose with the integral; even if you get the right answer, it’s like the physicist who “multiplies by $dt$“ to do calculus.